# Regex that match the occurrence of specific number before another specific number

Tags: regex

I'm new to regular expressions and trying to write a regex that matches two numbers,if one of them is before the other one then match, even if the second number is not after the first one immediately.
For example I want to match 6 and 2

These should match

```
62
1236982
```

Comment: `.*6.*2.*` Should work.

Comment: The one you wrote is good enough for me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the below regex.

```
.*?(?:6.*?2|2.*?6).*
```

OR

```
.*?(?:6\d*2|2\d*6).*
```

This match the lines where both the digits 6 and 2 must present. And this won't care about their positions.

Answer (score 1):

`6.*2` 
or `6[0-9]*2`  to restrict to numbers only